# Store images in local machine through Jquery-Ajax with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, node.js, ajax

I have **tried** some way to store the image that I `pick` from my `local machine`, then using Javascript (Jquery Ajax) to send the image into NodeJs Server. after that I get the image and store it again in a specific Path: `/MyNodejsProject/Public/images`, in My Machine.

**Nodejs Server to**

```
router.get('/imgupload' , (req , res)=>{
  var { file } = req.query;
  console.log(file);
}):
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.file-upload', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "users/imgupload",
        data: `file=${event.target.files}`,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function ({ msg }) {
            alert(msg)
        }
    });
})
```

And After picking the image from my Local Computer.

[image]

Show me Object `FileList`

[image]

If you have a way that helps me to doing what I want to do, please mention it I appreciate

Comment: you'll need a "POST" if you want to send an image from client to server - while a body on a "GET" is apparently a thing now on HTTP, browsers XMLHttpRequest will NOT send a body in a GET request ... and jqueeeeeery probably tries to convert that "body" to a URL search - and an image will make the URL "too long"

Comment: if you want to use nodejs with express (which you seem to be doing, not sure why you tagged sql since your question has naff all to do with sql, but you didn't tag expressjs) then you should do a search for "How to upload files in Node.js and Express"

Comment: Sure, I using expressJs but I find it more useful that ask using Nodejs terms,  I try to change the get into POST and I still have the Problem just the error message change from [Object FileList] to undefined

Comment: you probably don't use any body parser - am I right